# What command to defragment BTRFS partition using maximum compression?

Tags: 20.04

Using the command below
sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -v -r -czlib -f /
defragment an BTRFS partition root using compression zlib.
in fstab is possible select zlib compression 1 to 9.
Strange detail is that defrag command allow to select zlib, but not has any information if is possible select low or high compression.
trying to use czlib:9 or c zlib:9 result in error and not will run the command.
If using defrag command will use zlib compression settings from fstab ? will use maximum compression ? If not how is possible configure to use maximum compression ?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Is there anything in [this old reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84213/btrfs-defragmentation-of-files-folders) which helps?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The link has good information, but I need only understand if running defragment command using "czilb" will defragment using zlib maximum compression.